# Creating a working copy of a GIT repo

Tags: eclipse, git, atlassian-sourcetree

I am working with Git/SourceTree/Eclipse. I am cloning a GIT repo outside of my Eclipse workspace. SourceTree is now pointing to this location.

There is no .project file in GIT. So in Eclipse I create a new dynamic web project and import my GIT repo (including the .git folder) into it. The project builds just fine.

Now this means that any changes I make in Eclipse won't be reflected in SourceTree because the GIT repo is essentially in 2 places. So I'd have to make another repo in SourceTree just to point to my Eclipse workspace.

I cloned the GIT repo outside my workspace because I heard that's best practice. But surely there's got to be a simpler way.

What is that simpler way?

Thanks for any helpful tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you imported the folder with the `.git`-folder into your `workspace`-folder, you could just use that directory for your development now. You no longer need the original clone.

However, I'm guessing cloning inside the `workspace`-directory is considered bad practice because it can slow down your Eclipse-project (see [Is it better to keep Git repository inside or outside of Eclipse workspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531272/is-it-better-to-keep-git-repository-inside-or-outside-of-eclipse-workspace)).

Probably cloning with **EGit** could make your life easier because it can point to a `.git`-folder outside your `workspace`-folder. (http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Cloning_Remote_Repositories)

Comment: If I clone with EGit can I still manage my repo with SourceTree? Or would I be forced to do it in EGit?

Comment: Good point. I think SourceTree expects `.git` to be in the current directory so I would say NO but have to check on this. Note that you can also put Eclipse projects as subdirectories of a git repository which might solve the problem of having Eclipse slow down as it wouldn't try to access `.git` anymore. Technically the .git-repository is then still in your `workspace`-directory but it is out of your Eclipse project folder (which might also be referred to as "workspace").