# Where to put Git repository in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, git

If I try to put repository inside project folder

[image]

it warns it is not recommended to put git repository inside workspace.

If I try to create intermediate folder

[image]

it swears "overlaps the location of another project" at the stage of creating new project.

And if I try to create project inside workspace and repository outside, it moves the project also outside of workspace

[image]

So, the only way to use Git under Eclipse it totally abandon workspace?

Comment: Are you converting an existing project to Git, or are you trying to import a Git repository to Eclipse?

Comment: Neither. I would like to create NEW project and would like to store it well.

Comment: Put it outside of eclipse workspace into some folder for git projects.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it better to keep Git repository inside or outside of Eclipse workspace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531272/is-it-better-to-keep-git-repository-inside-or-outside-of-eclipse-workspace)

Answer (score 0):

If you choose the last solution you present, to deal with git and Eclipse, you will not abandon workspace, all your code will remain into your Project Workspace but you will get an additionnal folder somewhere else containing your same code, versioned, a local git repository. By choosing this solution, you can only version some parts of your project and you also  avoid some possible conflicts that can arise when versioning your workspace project folder. You can also have a cleaner view of your code if you want it without eclipse metadata and do some complex git tasks on the commandline in this separate folder.