# Workflow for creating new Maven project in Eclipse and bringing it to Github

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven, github

I want to create a new Maven project in Eclipse and push it to a new repository on github. I am a bit stuck on the right order of steps to achieve this.

- To use a Maven archetype, I cannot use a directory with files in it. So I cannot create a Maven project in a git local repository. So using the archetype should probably come first.
- I also need to create a repository in my github account. If I do this through the github desktop app, this already creates a local repository for me.
- Now I have an Eclipse project and a local repository, up to now unrelated. How should I "relate" them?

I found a lot of information about cloning from github, but my github repository does not have a Maven project yet, so I cannot import in Eclipse. If I use command line instead and an empty directory, I cannot apply Maven archetypes any more because the directory is not empty.

I am confused. Can somebody de-confuse me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I did the following:

1. I created a new Maven project with an archetype in the directory for github local repositories.
2. I used the github app to create repository with the same name in the same directory.
3. Then I published this repository to github.
4. Now I imported the project from the github local repository to eclipse.

The workflow is generally the one suggested by @lealceldeiro, but without using the command line git.

Answer (score 2):

- Create a new Maven project (however you want to create it). This, of course, will create a new directory in the file system with all the resources.
- [Create a repository in Github](https://help.github.com/en/articles/create-a-repo).
- From the command line (located inside the project directory) do `git init`. This will create the local repository inside that directory.
- Next, [add a remote](https://help.github.com/en/articles/adding-a-remote) to your local repository: `$ git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git` (optionally replace `origin` for the name your remote repository is going to be called, also replace `user` for your github username and `repo` for the name of your github repository name)
- Add all files to be commited in the local repository.

For example

```
$ git add .

# Adds the file to your local repository and stages it for commit. To unstage a file, use 'git reset HEAD YOUR-FILE'.
```

- Commit changes.

For example:

```
$ git commit -m "Add existing file"
# Commits the tracked changes and prepares them to be pushed to a remote repository. To remove this commit and modify the file, use 'git reset --soft HEAD~1' and commit and add the file again.
```

- [Push to remote](https://help.github.com/en/articles/pushing-to-a-remote).

Just be clear, taking the following structure as reference, What I propose is to have as git repositories any of the directories `project1`, `project2`, `projectN`, not the whole worspace (`/roo_dir/workspace/` directory).

```
/roo_dir/workspace/
            - project1
            - project2
            - projectN
```

Additional readings:

- [Considerations for Git Repositories to be used in Eclipse](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Considerations_for_Git_Repositories_to_be_used_in_Eclipse)
- [Should I store git repository in Home or Eclipse Workspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685246/should-i-store-git-repository-in-home-or-eclipse-workspace)
- [Is it better to keep Git repository inside or outside of Eclipse workspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531272/is-it-better-to-keep-git-repository-inside-or-outside-of-eclipse-workspace)

Comment: So in your workflow, the local repository gets created in the project directory? Then I probably need to create it outside the Eclipse workspace because git repositories in workspaces are not recommended.

Comment: Indeed, the local repository is in the project directory. That's the usual way to do it. I'm a bit confused about why git repositories in workspaces are not recommended, though. Here is some info about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531272/is-it-better-to-keep-git-repository-inside-or-outside-of-eclipse-workspace

Comment: @JFMeier see the last part of the (updated) answer. The idea is to have as git repository the directory containing the resources itself, not the whole worspace

Comment: I usually follow more or less the same step as @JFMeier, I don't really care much if Eclipse dosen't find it agreeable, because the project should not be dependent on the IDE you use...

Comment: But if Eclipse performance degrades, this is not really good, especially if you have several projects...

Comment: @JFMeier I have used eclipse with HUGE projects using the workflow I just described and performance has not been an issue, really. I recommend you to try this out and see how it works for your specific use case. If you have some spare time, let me know how it goes :)

Comment: I guess performance issues could be a problem, but I never experienced such problems because of git. I must say that I use git from command line to make commits and push / pull operation, it's less _automatic_, a more _deliberate_ action if you will. Then i also .gitignore all files eclipse related. So I really don't know if EGit has problems dealing with such a layout.

Comment: @minus, I must say, I use EGit for tasks such as _commits_, and git console for _pull_ / _push_ / _rebase_, etc and have never experienced any performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

- Create a blank project in git hub
- create a maven project in local
- clone the git repo
- this will not have any file
- copy the maven project
- add the files to git and push

Comment: while creating the git hub project include the .gitIgnore for maven